# Please make "low-disk-space" a synonym for "internal storage"

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Android devices don't have "disks". As such, [low-disk-space](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-disk-space) should be a synonym of [internal-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-storage).

The latter is for all issues dealing with internal storage, not just its lack.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with the merge, I don't think it's possible to specialize in solving low space issues / errors so the tag doesn't create a useful category.  I'll wait to see if anyone else has thoughts though.

Comment: My only comment is that I believe the status bar warning Android gives you does use the text "Low disk space" on some (all?) devices, although I don't necessarily think that's a compelling enough reason to keep the tag around.

Comment: A good reason for keeping it as a synonym.

Comment: I agree with the merge and keeping the synonym since the OS does do as @eldareathis says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and did this merge, and [low-disk-space](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-disk-space) is now a synonym of [internal-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-storage).