# `low-disk-space` pointing to wrong master?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I've just noticed the tag synonym [low-disk-space](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-disk-space) points to [internal-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-storage). Shouldn't it rather point to [insufficient-memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory)?

That synonym [was created in 2012](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/965/16575), migrated from being a stand-alone tag. The [insufficient-memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) tag has [been created 2013](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1362/16575).

Comment: Obvious historical mistake. Go ahead and re-synonymize them.

Comment: My thought, indeed. Now I just need to figure out how to accomplish that (remapping a synonym) …

Comment: Remapping done (another "first" for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a historical mistake and should have been corrected as soon as we had [insufficient-memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory).

The original synonym proposal by *ale* stated:

> Android devices don't have "disks". As such, [low-disk-space](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/low-disk-space) should be a synonym of [internal-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/internal-storage).
>
> **The latter is for all issues dealing with internal storage, not just its lack.**

Note, that it was no longer true since [insufficient-memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) was introduced in 2013, so it should have been corrected (by then).